# How is dispatch_debug supposed to be used?

Tags: iphone, multithreading, debugging, grand-central-dispatch

I am struggling with a deadlock in my GCD code. Then I saw this function `dispatch_debug` in the header file `<dispatch/object.h>`.

```
/*!
 * @function dispatch_debug
 *
 * @abstract
 * Programmatically log debug information about a dispatch object.
 *
 * @param object
 * The object to introspect.
 *
 * @param message
 * The message to log above and beyond the introspection.
 */
__OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_10_6,__IPHONE_4_0)
DISPATCH_EXPORT DISPATCH_NONNULL2 DISPATCH_NOTHROW __attribute__((__format__(printf,2,3)))
void
dispatch_debug(dispatch_object_t object, const char *message, ...);
```

But I am not able to make it do anything. I was hoping it would print out the state and locks or something like that.

Here is how I use it:

```
grabber_queue = dispatch_queue_create("com.unpaq.tvguideplus.grabber", NULL);
dispatch_debug(grabber_queue, "grabber queue");
```

Comment: Looking at it, I strongly suspect that that is part of the private SDK which we aren't supposed to use. In which case the answer is "you don't".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- [Grand Central Dispatch (GCD) Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html)

> dispatch_debug
>
> Debug information is logged to the Console log. This information can be useful as a debugging tool to view the internal state (current reference count, suspension count, etc.) of a dispatch object at the time the dispatch_debug function is called.

dispatch_debug sends messages to syslog. So,

```
grabber_queue = dispatch_queue_create("com.unpaq.tvguideplus.grabber", NULL);
dispatch_debug(grabber_queue, "grabber queue");
```

this code would print as the following in system.log.

```
May 13 08:50:17 hostname exefile[53164]: com.unpaq.tvguideplus.grabber[0x6200e10] = {
 xrefcnt = 0x1, refcnt = 0x1, suspend_cnt = 0x0, locked = 0, target =
 com.apple.root.default-overcommit-priority[0x1af0700], width = 0x0, running = 0x0,
 barrier = 0 }: grabber queueMay
```

It doesn't appear in Xcode debug console. You can see in /Applications/Utilities/Console.app system.log on the iPhone simulator, or in Xcode organizer on iPhone, iPod touch and iPad.

By the way, GCD is open source. It is distributed via [libdispatch](http://libdispatch.macosforge.org/). dispatch_debug is included in src/object.c.

- [src/object.c - dispatch_debug](http://libdispatch.macosforge.org/trac/browser/trunk/src/object.c)

Comment: Excellent. Too bad I am not able to see it in the debug console. But at least now I know why.

Comment: On behalf of @DoDoDoiT: @"I got confused with System.log on the iPhone simulator. To find system.log file, in finder, go to /Applications/Utilities/Console.app In a panel on left hand side, you will find system.log under FILES drop down menu"

Comment: You can redirect the output to the console - see dispatch_debug on this blog: http://jeremywsherman.com/blog/2013/01/08/debugdescription-gcd-xpc/

Comment: Can you please tell me what's locked = 0 means?

Comment: According to http://libdispatch.macosforge.org/trac/browser/trunk/src/object.c#L288 , "locked = 0" means the object is not suspended.

Comment: This function is now deprecated: see the answer from @werediver below

Answer (score 1):

As of iOS 6.0 `dispatch_debug()` is [deprecated](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/dispatch_debug). The docs doesn't say what is intended to be used instead, but I found out that now you can handle `dispatch_object_t` objects like `NSObject` ones:

```
(lldb) po _connectScanTimer
<OS_dispatch_source: kevent-source[0x15d47440] = { xrefcnt = 0x1, refcnt = 0x2, suspend_cnt = 0x7fffffff, locked = 0, target = [0x15d7ca50], ident = 0x4, pending_data = 0x1, pending_data_mask = 0x0, timer = { target = 0x48841e442a, deadline = 0x488479d1aa, last_fire = 0x48808ac1cc, interval = 0x3938700, flags = 0x0 }, filter = DISPATCH_EVFILT_TIMER }>
```

That means you can use `description` and [`debugDescription`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/technotes/tn2124/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10003391-CH1-SECCOCOA) methods to get some info about `dispatch_object_t` objects.